# Override error representation on import model page django

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export, django-admin-tools

I'm working with a django application and don't wanted to show users the stack trace when there is any error occurred in production.

For example, I've added validation to validate import action under `before_import` method, and when there is any issue in the validation it shows error message along with stack trace. Please refer screenshot below:

[image]

Instead I wanted to just show the error message only. This is mainly for the security purpose as on production it will disclose my server directory structure to it's users.

I tried couple of things,

1. to override `import.html` under my templates directory, but it didn't worked.
2. to override exception using LOGGING in settings.py

It is great, if I can show list of errors for all affected rows in a CSV/XLSX file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can control the formatting of the error message if required.  Please refer to the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-hide-stack-trace-in-ui-error-messages).

I also recently updated the documentation about [best practices with validation](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/release-4/docs/advanced_usage.rst#validation-during-import).  In your example, you could consider writing a custom widget to do the coupon validation.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, you really made my day.

One more question, is there a way we can preview all errors/issues in a CSV or XLSX in a tabular format instead of returning error for a particular field?

Comment: Yes, you can do this if you generate the errors correctly ([example](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/release-4/docs/_static/images/date-widget-validation-error.png)).  Refer to the [docs](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/release-4/docs/advanced_usage.rst#validation-during-import) for more information.  Raise a new question if you need any help with it.